# (C) Incompatible pointer type [LPCWSTR]

Tags: c, winapi, types

I am receiving **incompatible pointer type everywhere** when I am trying to **work with unicode `LPCWSTR` types**.

I am completely stuck no matter what I do, tried to search for a answer lots of times and still no hope!

My code:

```
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include "Mouse.h"
#include "Keyboard.h"
//#define APP_WindowClassName "MOUSE_CLICKER"
//#define APP_WindowTitle "Mouse Clicker"

LRESULT CALLBACK app_WindowProcedure (HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (uMsg) {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) { // Arg1 - A handle to the current instance of the application, Arg 2 - ???, Arg 3 - Arguments, Arg 4 - Controls how the window is to be shown.

    WNDCLASSEXW main_WindowClass = { };
    main_WindowClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEXA);
    main_WindowClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    main_WindowClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    main_WindowClass.hInstance = hInstance;
    main_WindowClass.lpfnWndProc = app_WindowProcedure;
    main_WindowClass.lpszClassName = TEXT("MOUSE_CLICKER");
    main_WindowClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    main_WindowClass.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH) (TEXT(COLOR_BACKGROUND));
    main_WindowClass.hCursor = LoadCursorW (NULL, TEXT(IDC_ARROW));
    main_WindowClass.hIcon = LoadIconW(NULL, TEXT(IDI_APPLICATION));
    main_WindowClass.hIconSm = LoadIconW(NULL, TEXT(IDI_APPLICATION));
    main_WindowClass.style = CS_DBLCLKS;

    //CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW a


    if (RegisterClassExW(&main_WindowClass) == 0) {
        printf ("[CRITICAL] main_WindowClass cannot be registered!");
        return -1;
    }

    HWND main_WindowHandle = CreateWindowExW (0, TEXT("MOUSE_CLICKER"), TEXT("MouseClicker"), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 0, 0, 800, 600, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if (main_WindowHandle == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }

    ShowWindow(main_WindowHandle, nCmdShow);

    printf("Unicode: %d", IsWindowUnicode(main_WindowHandle));

    MSG ProcessingMessage;
    while (GetMessage(&ProcessingMessage, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&ProcessingMessage);
        DispatchMessage(&ProcessingMessage);
    }
    return ProcessingMessage.wParam;

}
```

My build log picture link:

[image: warnings]

PS: I am a beginner in C (still learning) and understandable descriptive information on what I am doing wrong would be nice.

PS2: To avoid confusion **this is pure C, NOT C++**.

Solution code:

```
#if defined(UNICODE) && !defined(_UNICODE)
    #define _UNICODE
#elif defined(_UNICODE) && !defined(UNICODE)
    #define UNICODE
#endif

#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include "Mouse.h"
#include "Keyboard.h"

LRESULT CALLBACK app_WindowProcedure (HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (uMsg) {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);

    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) { // Arg1 - A handle to the current instance of the application, Arg 2 - ???, Arg 3 - Arguments, Arg 4 - Controls how the window is to be shown.

    WNDCLASSEXW main_WindowClass = { };
    main_WindowClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEXA);
    main_WindowClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    main_WindowClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    main_WindowClass.hInstance = hInstance;
    main_WindowClass.lpfnWndProc = app_WindowProcedure;
    main_WindowClass.lpszClassName = L"MOUSE_CLICKER";
    main_WindowClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    main_WindowClass.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH) (COLOR_BACKGROUND);
    main_WindowClass.hCursor = LoadCursorW (NULL, (LPCWSTR) IDC_ARROW);
    main_WindowClass.hIcon = LoadIconW(NULL, (LPCWSTR) IDI_APPLICATION);
    main_WindowClass.hIconSm = LoadIconW(NULL, (LPCWSTR) IDI_APPLICATION);
    main_WindowClass.style = CS_DBLCLKS;

    //CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW a


    if (RegisterClassExW(&main_WindowClass) == 0) {
        printf ("[CRITICAL] main_WindowClass cannot be registered!");
        return -1;
    }

    HWND main_WindowHandle = CreateWindowExW (0, L"MOUSE_CLICKER", L"MouseClicker", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 0, 0, 800, 600, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if (main_WindowHandle == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }

    ShowWindow(main_WindowHandle, nCmdShow);

    printf("Unicode: %d", IsWindowUnicode(main_WindowHandle));

    MSG ProcessingMessage;
    while (GetMessage(&ProcessingMessage, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&ProcessingMessage);
        DispatchMessage(&ProcessingMessage);
    }
    return ProcessingMessage.wParam;

}
```

Comment: But those are warnings.

Comment: I did try L and _L instead of TEXT that is used for LPCWSTR conversion, still no hope.

Comment: Those warnings crashes my app, makes main_WindowClass fail to be registered. If ANSI is used I don't have any issues, but I want UNICODE.

Comment: Updated build log: http://prntscr.com/f3dje1

Comment: You are supposed to put the relevant part of the compiler message in **text** form directly in the question, not on some external site, which might go offline at any time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define `UNICODE` in your project.

Based on whether `UNICODE` is defined, `TEXT` expands to either `LPSTR` or `LPWSTR`. You are explicitly calling `*W` versions of WinAPI functions but pass `LPSTR` instead of `LPWSTR`. Prefixing string literal with `L` should work actually. Maybe you used it as `L("foo")` - it won't work this way. You need to use `L"foo"`.

Overall, if you use `TEXT`, you should use WinAPI functions without suffixes, so that code will compile both with and without `UNICODE` defined. If you explicitly use `*W` functions, use `L""` strings.

Comment: Thank you! I've been searching ages for this.

Comment: I disagree with your final paragraph; better to use `L` constant strings rather than `TEXT` so that the code won't build if `UNICODE` isn't defined.  The first reason is that you should *always* have `UNICODE` defined, and the second reason is that code that compiles in either mode tends to be buggy, because it is usually only tested in one mode or the other.  (And it is almost never worth the effort anyway.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston I didn't mean that one should prefer using `TEXT` over `L`, I just said that `TEXT` goes with functions without suffixes and `L` goes with `*W` functions. I agree that in 2017 you should not use ANSI versions at all, you may need `TEXT` and `_T` only if you are working on some legacy code.

Comment: There is no reason to use generic-text mappings even with legacy code either. Be explicit when using character encodings. If your build breaks, you can fix it. If it compiles, even though it shouldn't, because the generic-text mappings stepped up to help, this is far worse.

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaches you can take to get this to work; since you're already going down the path of using [Generic-Text Mappings in `Tchar.h`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c426s321.aspx), let's continue on that route.

Here is the main body of your program, revised to run as Unicode when your project is set to build Unicode.

(A side "benefit", if you would call it that, is that you *can* run your application as an ASCII application as well just by changing the character set of the project.)

```
LRESULT CALLBACK app_WindowProcedure(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (uMsg) {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) { // Arg1 - A handle to the current instance of the application, Arg 2 - ???, Arg 3 - Arguments, Arg 4 - Controls how the window is to be shown.

    WNDCLASSEX main_WindowClass = {};
    main_WindowClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    main_WindowClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    main_WindowClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    main_WindowClass.hInstance = hInstance;
    main_WindowClass.lpfnWndProc = app_WindowProcedure;
    main_WindowClass.lpszClassName = TEXT("MOUSE_CLICKER");
    main_WindowClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    main_WindowClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_BACKGROUND);
    main_WindowClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    main_WindowClass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    main_WindowClass.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    main_WindowClass.style = CS_DBLCLKS;

    //CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW a


    if (RegisterClassEx(&main_WindowClass) == 0) {
        _tprintf(TEXT("[CRITICAL] main_WindowClass cannot be registered!"));
        return -1;
    }

    HWND main_WindowHandle = CreateWindowEx(0, TEXT("MOUSE_CLICKER"), TEXT("MouseClicker"), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 0, 0, 800, 600, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if (main_WindowHandle == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }

    ShowWindow(main_WindowHandle, nCmdShow);

    _tprintf(TEXT("Unicode: %d"), IsWindowUnicode(main_WindowHandle));

    MSG ProcessingMessage;
    while (GetMessage(&ProcessingMessage, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&ProcessingMessage);
        DispatchMessage(&ProcessingMessage);
    }
    return ProcessingMessage.wParam;

}
```

Note that Unicode-specific function calls were replaced with their generic counterparts (e.g., `DefWindowProcW`() is now `DefWindowProc()`; `RegisterClassExW`() is now `RegisterClassEx`(); `printf`() is now `_tprintf`(), and so on).  All text is wrapped in the `TEXT`() macro.

An alternative approach, as you worked in part, is to make all API calls the `...W` versions for Unicode functions, and to hard-code text using the `L` prefix to use Unicode text.

A good rule of thumb is to try to pick one technique or another, and apply it consistently and across the board.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include "Mouse.h"
#include "Keyboard.h"
//#define APP_WindowClassName "MOUSE_CLICKER"
//#define APP_WindowTitle "Mouse Clicker"

LRESULT CALLBACK app_WindowProcedure(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (uMsg) {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) { // Arg1 - A handle to the current instance of the application, Arg 2 - ???, Arg 3 - Arguments, Arg 4 - Controls how the window is to be shown.

    WNDCLASSEXW main_WindowClass = *((WNDCLASSEXW*)malloc(sizeof(WNDCLASSEXW)));
    main_WindowClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEXA);
    main_WindowClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    main_WindowClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    main_WindowClass.hInstance = hInstance;
    main_WindowClass.lpfnWndProc = app_WindowProcedure;
    main_WindowClass.lpszClassName = L"MOUSE_CLICKER";
    main_WindowClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    main_WindowClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_BACKGROUND);
    main_WindowClass.hCursor = LoadCursorW(NULL, (LPWSTR)IDC_ARROW);
    main_WindowClass.hIcon = LoadIconW(NULL, (LPWSTR)IDI_APPLICATION);
    main_WindowClass.hIconSm = LoadIconW(NULL, (LPWSTR)IDI_APPLICATION);
    main_WindowClass.style = CS_DBLCLKS;

    //CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW a


    if (RegisterClassExW(&main_WindowClass) == 0) {
        printf("[CRITICAL] main_WindowClass cannot be registered!");
        return -1;
    }

    HWND main_WindowHandle = CreateWindowExW(0, L"MOUSE_CLICKER", L"MouseClicker", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 0, 0, 800, 600, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if (main_WindowHandle == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }

    ShowWindow(main_WindowHandle, nCmdShow);

    printf("Unicode: %d", IsWindowUnicode(main_WindowHandle));

    MSG ProcessingMessage;
    while (GetMessage(&ProcessingMessage, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&ProcessingMessage);
        DispatchMessage(&ProcessingMessage);
    }
    return ProcessingMessage.wParam;

}
```

Comment: *"This should work: <wall of code>"* type of answers aren't useful. Without explaining, what the issue is and how the changes address that, this answer isn't exactly valuable.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to stackoverflow, I'll try to improve my answer when I have time.

Comment: Being new is not a problem. Being new and ignoring to take in the advice (by skipping to take the [tour], which you were offered), on the other hand, is.